# If "X" is a synonym of "Y", and you try to merge "Y" into "X", the merge fails with a generic error page

Tags: feature-request, bug, moderator-tools, tag-merge-utility

If you have a tag "X", which is a synonym to the master tag "Y", and then you try to merge "Y" into "X" (with the "These two tags are synonyms" box checked), the merge preview succeeds, but the merge itself fails and sends you to a generic "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error page.

It would be better if either the preview would tell me that I'm doing something stupid and stop me from trying to go ahead, or at least if a specific error message could be thrown rather than the generic "Oops!" page.

(Why would I even do something stupid like this? Because I forgot that you can just click "swap" on /tags/synonyms to do this instead.)

Comment: Heh, I was just looking at our exception log and thinking "we should really just show an error message in this case"... Thanks for writing it up!

Comment: So bug or feature request, @Anna? Or some abomination in between? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Abomination. This is technically a request to change current behaviour that I'm pretty sure is by design... but at the same time, the design is so ridiculous that, you know. :)

Comment: @Anna lol, so it fits your new avatar... kudos! :D

Comment: A while back on Japanese.SE, I tried to create a tag synonym, and it failed because there was already a tag synonym *suggestion* going the other way.  Of course, the error message didn't tell me that, so I needed help to figure it out...

Comment: Apparently, BoltClock posted a bug report for snailboat's issue a while back: [Tag merging with synonym mapping \[foo\] → \[bar\] fails if proposal for \[bar\] → \[foo\] exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175176/)