# I think I managed to break some tag synonyms somehow

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

Preface: please refrain from editing the posts/tags I reference in this post, because you might make the bug vanish.

Extra preface: this issue is probably the result of misuse of diamond moderator tools. Attempts to reproduce this issue without a diamond will probably be futile.

---

On Anime.SE, we have the tags "waiting-in-the-summer" and "ano-natsu-de-matteru". Currently, it appears that the former is a synonym (slave) of the latter (master). However, these tags are misbehaving.

## Issue 1

On the tag synonyms page, there's this:

[image: https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms]

Though "waiting-in-the-summer" is an approved synonym of "ano-natsu-de-matteru", it is the synonym tag "waiting-in-the-summer" that is listed as having questions ("× 1"). For every other approved master-synonym pair, it is the master that is listed as having questions.

## Issue 2

There is a merge option there. I don't know why. This may not be a bug, but this is the only pair for which I see a merge option, so it's at minimum somewhat curious.

## Issue 3

[/tags/ano-natsu-de-matteru/synonyms](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/ano-natsu-de-matteru/synonyms) 404s. Other master tags have a /tags/$tagname/synonyms page, and other synonym tags redirect to the /tags/$tagname/synonyms page for their master tag, so the 404 is probably not supposed to happen.

## Issue 4

[/questions/tagged/ano-natsu-de-matteru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ano-natsu-de-matteru) lacks the widget that shows you the tag wiki excerpt along with the "learn more...", "top users", and "synonyms" links. This means I can't edit the tag wiki for this tag. Le horror!

([/questions/tagged/waiting-in-the-summer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waiting-in-the-summer) redirects there.)

---

I am not entirely sure how I managed to create this issue, but I suspect this had something to do with me trying to misuse the tag-merge utility, as described here: [If "X" is a synonym of "Y", and you try to merge "Y" into "X", the merge fails with a generic error page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257823/). I suspect I could resolve the issue by either editing and retagging the question, or de-tagging it and letting the 3am tag-deleter to run, or something like that. But I haven't done that so as to preserve this issue so that SE staff can investigate or whatever.

I don't think this is a straightforward caching issue, since it's been over 24 hours since I performed any operations on these tags, and I don't think anybody else has touched them.

Comment: I often find it useful if you encounter what you think is a bug with moderators tools to make it more obvious you are a diamond mod on the site in question.  Not everyone who  visits this site regularly is a mod someplace.  At least by saying "I am a mod on Anime.SE and I ran into this issue", it makes it more obvious I will not have much to offer and I should turn and run away.

Comment: [/info also 404´s](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/ano-natsu-de-matteru/info)

Comment: Yeah, when you see something weird... don't keep trying things. :) I'm not in a position to dig into it right now, but I'll see what's what when I can look at the code again. (Unless someone else beats me to it, obvs.)